# Storing floating point numbers in struct in C

Tags: c, printf

I created a struct variable. An example of this is:

```
    struct numbers
    {
        float start;
        float end;
        int middle;
    }values;

    int main()
    {
        scanf("%f %f %d", &values.start, &values.end, &values.middle);
        printf("%f %f %d, &values.start, &values.end, &values.middle);
    }
```

When I try to read values into these variables through user input, such as "0 5.8 3". When I try to print, it looks like this

0.000000 0.0000000 -26148776 (The last number changes everytime I run the program, and the rest remain as 0)

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why & in printf??

Comment: You pass addresses to `printf`. Don't just copy from `scanf`. Read the specification.

Comment: In the future when posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please copy-paste some working code instead of retyping it into the question. If you retype then it can lead you to add other unrelated errors and problems, like you have done with the unterminated string. Or maybe even fix the problem you ask about, without realizing it.

Comment: The function `scanf` returns some value. You should not just ignore it. Check it to verify how many parameters were parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`scanf` family](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) of functions needs pointers so it knows where to store the results.

The [`printf` family](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) of functions prints ***values***, so it does not need pointers.

When you have a mismatch between `printf` format specification and argument, then it leads to *undefined behavior*.

So the simple solution is to not use the address-of operator `&` for the arguments in your `printf` call.